# intellij spring boot build error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have errors when building spring-boot application with IntelliJ. When I click 'Build' on IntelliJ it gives me a list of errors, but if I mvn clean install, then it builds perfectly. Maybe anyone knows if this could be a bug or wrong configurations?

[image: IntelliJ screen with errors]

**Main.class**

```
package com.manvydas.bachelor;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

main class has has only run method

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.manvydas</groupId>
    <artifactId>bachelor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>manvydas-bachelor-project</name>
    <description>Manvydas bachelor project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nulab-inc</groupId>
            <artifactId>zxcvbn</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: show me a screenshot of the run configuration as well

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jf9qiv

Comment: Shouldnt your working directory be `$MODULE_DIR` instead of `$MAVEN_REPOSITORY`  ?

Comment: you mean in pom.xml? No, I try to do 2.0.1 project from the beggining

Comment: $MODULE_DIR change did nothing. The error occurs when project is building, not running

Comment: oh shoot. I tried too that doesn't affect the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something is wrong with your IntelliJ configuration. However, you can run your application typing in IntelliJ's terminal the command `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your IntelliJ artifact build is not creating the same package that your Maven pom does.

You should look at your project artifact to make sure that you end up with precisely the same package, regardless of whether you use IntelliJ or Maven to create it.

Comment: I am having the same problem as well. Not sure what you meant by your answer:
the artifact is created successfully by maven and works independently. its group is identical to the package structure. Can you elaborate what you meant ?

Comment: Open the two JARs and compare them.  I don't believe they are identical.

Comment: "the two jars": I guess you mean the ones created in the target folder: the original and of spring? (as there aren't any defined artifacts other than the maven's ones)
If so, I checked them both and they have similar packaging structures (as expected).
(and if not, can you explain what you meant ?)

Comment: There should be one that IntelliJ created and another that Maven created.  Similar package structure is not enough.  You need to look ITEM BY ITEM to see if they are identical.

Comment: AFAIK,  (and double checked), when loading maven project on intellij, it does not create its own artifacts; it relies only on maven's. so no other jars are produced other than maven target folder (e.g. no 'out' folder as well).
I will also add that I COULD NOT reproduce this problem on a different machine. on a different machine the project structure looks exactly the same as the one that fails on my machine.

Comment: No other JARs produced?  I can create an executable JAR with a Maven plugin.  That's what Spring Boot does routinely.  Close your question if you can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Please have in mind that after several (mis-)configuration steps IntelliJ might get in a state where it is not able to recognize Spring anymore. I had this situation sometimes. Then just delete Caches (File->Invalidate Caches...), just the index option worked for me. In our team, we saw this working several times on different machines (IntelliJ 2021.1, Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same error.
I created a new project by-the-book of spring boot (with only web-starter). I did not add any code and invoked it as it is, right after its creation. I was successful with mvn clean install (jar runs and is operative), but intellij invocation (that involves the own intellij build step) fails due to missing org.springframework.boot package. (you can see in the image that the package is recognizable by intellij. it's only a problem of the build step)

I am after all the attempts of invalidate cache; restarted intellij; I have re-installed intellij completely and upgraded to latest 2022.3 ultimate version. running on java 17 on windows 11 (as much as it matters); I have sent my project to other team mates and it works flawlessly on their machine (as expected).
[image]

It seems that something got hanged and ruined on my intellij configuration, and the step of 'build' cannot get aligned with maven's artifacts